# A and B play until one has 5 more points than the other…

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question: Player A and B play until one has 5 more points than the other. Assuming that each point is independently won by A with probability p and by B with probability 1 - p, What is the probability that A is declared the winner?

I understand from similar questions that for questions like this where the geometric progress can be used to find the sum of all probabilities but I am having a hard time figuring out how to find the ratio of the pattern
of

$^5$+$^5$(5p(1-p))+...
or 
$p^5(1+5p(1-p)$+....)

Would be very grateful to receive any constructive feedback regarding my question. Thank you!

Comment: I would try a Markov approach.  We have running states $S_4,S_3,\cdots, S_{-3},S_{-4}$ indexed by the difference between their scores (say $S_4$ means $A$ is up by $4$ and so on).  And we have states  $S_5$ and $S_{-5}$ corresponding to $A$ wins and $B$ wins.  Easy to compute the transition probabilities between them and work from there.

Comment: Exploiting conditional probabilities (and the fact that the game goes on forever with probability zero), the probability that $A$ wins should be $\frac{p^5}{p^5+(1-p)^5}$ and the probability that $B$ wins should be $\frac{(1-p)^5}{p^5+(1-p)^5}$. @lulu: am I wrong?

Comment: It is enough to show that $$\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\text{ wins}]}{\mathbb{P}[B\text{ wins}]}=\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^5,$$ and this can be done by induction on the number of extra points needed to win.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you explain how the induction goes, please?  I'm having trouble seeing it.  My problem is that the probability that A gets ahead by $n-1$ points in the $n$-point game is not the same as the probability that he wins the $n-1$-point game, so I don't see how to proceed from $n-1$ to $n$.  I feel like I should condition on something, but I don't see what.

Comment: @saulspatz: the point is that, in order to win the $n$-points game, $A$ needs to win the $(n-1)$-points game first. So if we consider *the ratio* $\rho_n=\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\text{ wins}]}{\mathbb{P}[B\text{ wins}]}$ in the $n$-points game, we get that $\rho_n=\frac{p}{1-p}\rho_{n-1}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  As with Gambler's Ruin, we can easily solve the recursion. Indeed, the problems are equivalent (just say $A$ starts with $5$ and seeks to reach $10$ before ruin). The characteristic polynomial is $px^2-x+(p-1)$ which has distinct roots at $\frac {1-p}p$ and $1$, ignoring the case $p=\frac 12$.  A little algebra then gets $P_n=\frac {r^{n+5}-1 }{r^{10}-1}$ where $r$ is the ratio $\frac {1-p}p$.  Taking $n=0$ gives the result...yes?

Comment: @lulu: perfect, we reached the same conclusion from two slightly different standpoints, I feel satisfied now.

Comment: @lulu would the transition probabilities be something like this? thanks again for the help!  
(−5)=(-4)+4∗(1−)  
(−4)=(-3)+3∗(1−)  
(−3)=(-2)+2∗(1−)  
(−2)=(-1)+1∗(1−)  
(−1)=(0)+0∗(1−)  
(0)=(1)+(−1)(1−)  
(1)=1∗+(0)(1−)  
(2)=2∗+(1)(1−)  
(3)=3∗+(2)(1−)  
(4)=4∗+(3)(1−)  
(5)=5∗+(4)(1−)

Comment: @kekeke12  Yes.  I find it clearer to just write the basic recursion, $p_n=p\times p_{n+1}+(1-p)\times p_{n-2}$ with boundary conditions $p_5=1$ and $p_{-5}=0$.  As I mentioned in an earlier comment, that recursion is easily solved, though of course nothing stops you from solving it as a system of linear equations.  It's $9$ equations though, so I think it might be easier to look at the recursion.

Comment: @kekeke12  Sorry, there's a typo in my last comment.  The final probability ought to be $p_{n-1}$.